# Adding remaining IDs to an excel sheet mac

Tags: microsoft-excel

My sheet contains about 14000 rows. There are about 500 rows that have already an ID. The rest don't. Those IDs are not continuous, e.g. one record has ID 50, the next one has 140 and so on.

I want to keep the current ids for these records and also add IDs to the other rows, in between the gaps of the above IDs.

Looking for any suggestions on how to approach this, in order to get what I need.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but before you spent a lot of effort on doing this excel: If you have lots of data (and 14k rows is a lot) then consider it storing in program written for that kind of usage. E.g. a full database (SQL, oracle, ...) or in a light database (e.g. nosql, access.exe, ...).  That might save you a lot of work later **and** any database will adds a (primary) key to a record which will be unique and which can solve your question.

Comment: What is the problem with my question? What is the unclear part?

Comment: Next time posting an example data table or a screenshot would help.

Comment: Those that downvoted my question would you care share a comment on the reasons, why this is not a good question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the number of rows is somewhat large, making the use of excel extremely slow, in conjunction with the lack of any other workable suggestion, I worked this out with some php.

I created a php file (which I run it on my local MAMP) in order to run the below code, that would print the numbers I needed on the browser.

**In php:**
It was easy to wrap the existent ids in an array. Then, I created another array for the ids within the range of  my total rows. Then I echo the list of ids while excluding those that exist in the $used array.

```
$used = array ('42', '43', '44', '45',...)

$ids = array();

for ($min= 45;$min <15000;$min++) {
    $ids[]=$min;
}

foreach ($ids as $id) {

    if (!in_array($id,$used)) {echo $id ."<br />";}

}
```

So in my browser page, I got a line-separated list with numbers , which I copied and pasted in my excel sheet.

Comment: Downvoter, After struggling with my problem, I posted how I managed to overcome this, which might be helpful for others... Would you care sharing your thoughts for downvoting the solution I ended up with to solve my problem, with a comment? Or better if you have a better workable solution why won't you share with us?